# I have tried using ajax to call into my php function but i dont know whats wrong with the code its not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, ajaxform

```
 !-- Main Page Starts Here -->
  <section class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="centerlogin">
         <div class="frmlogin">
          <form role="form" name="signin" id="signin" method="post" action="#">
          <div class="headtab"><h3>Login</h3></div>
          <ul>    
          <li><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" id="email" name="username" class="usern" placeholder="Enter Username"></li>
          <li><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock">&nbsp;</i><input type="password" id="pwd" name="password" class="passn" placeholder="Enter Password"></li>
          <li><button class="subn" id="btnSubmit">Login</button></li>
         </ul>
         </form>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>
  </section>
  <!-- Main Page Ends Here -->
```

the above is my login form.

and below is my ajax call

```js
//ajax calls start below
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnSubmit").click(function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();
        var email = $("#email").val();
        var password = $("#pwd").val();
        var pwd = $.md5(password);
        auth(email, pwd);
        });
        });

        //authenticate function to make ajax call
        function auth(email, pwd) {
        $.ajax
        ({
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://localhost/main/web/sign-in",
        dataType: 'json',
        type : "POST",
        data: { email: email,pwd: pwd },
        success: function (r) {
          //console.log(r);
          if(r.status == '0')
          {
            var sk=r.sk;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://localhost/main/secret/signin.php",
                type : "POST",
                data: { sk:sk},
                success: function(r)
                {
                  if(r == '0')
                  {
                     window.location.href = "http://localhost/main/index.php";
                  }
                  else
                  {
                    window.location.href = "http://localhost/main/login.php";
                    alert('Something Went Wrong.Please Try Again!');
                  }
                }

              });
          }
          else if(r.status == '401')
          {
            alert("Incorrect Email/Password");
            $("#signin")[0].reset();
          }
          else
          {
            alert("User Doesn't exist");
            $("#signin")[0].reset();
          }
        return false;
        }

        
      });
    }
```

I dont know whats wrong with my code even the code its not working, it is not even showing the alerts on form blank inputs and form gets reload after clicking login button,Please help me stuck very badly.

Comment: remove *https*  here url: "http://localhost/main/web/sign-in",

Comment: which are the .js libraries used in your script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type property in Ajax call is defined twice.

Please use debugging tool, such as Firebug to debug xhr requests to understand if they are being sent or not. You can also view the responses of those requests which might hint errors.

Comment: i used firebug and used console to find out the issues and now it is solved

Answer (score 0):

Try below code as i have just removed http:// from url. hope this helps.

```
//ajax calls start below
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnSubmit").click(function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();
        var email = $("#email").val();
        var password = $("#pwd").val();
        var pwd = $.md5(password);
        auth(email, pwd);
        });
        });

        //authenticate function to make ajax call
        function auth(email, pwd) {
        $.ajax
        ({
        type: "POST",
        url: "web/sign-in",
        dataType: 'json',
        type : "POST",
        data: { email: email,pwd: pwd },
        success: function (r) {
          //console.log(r);
          if(r.status == '0')
          {
            var sk=r.sk;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "secret/signin.php",
                type : "POST",
                data: { sk:sk},
                success: function(r)
                {
                  if(r == '0')
                  {
                     window.location.href = "main/index.php";
                  }
                  else
                  {
                    window.location.href = "main/login.php";
                    alert('Something Went Wrong.Please Try Again!');
                  }
                }

              });
          }
          else if(r.status == '401')
          {
            alert("Incorrect Email/Password");
            $("#signin")[0].reset();
          }
          else
          {
            alert("User Doesn't exist");
            $("#signin")[0].reset();
          }
        return false;
        }


      });
    }
```

Comment: Its not Working out!

Comment: can you please share website files and folder structure? then i will making a changes for you in urls.

Comment: i solved it just had to put my jquery code after the jquery library now it is working out...

Answer (score 0):

Code is working after i change the sequence of my javascript files into my html file of my form.

I place my javascript code file after

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and It was working perfectly.